# How can I transfer a users information in a dashboard page after he/she logs in?

Tags: java, mysql, session, swing, netbeans

I am developing a Bank Management Project. Now I am stuck in a point. I want to create a login page where a user will submit his/her username and password then after clicks on the login button, a new page will arrive and show his information on text fields or panels. So how can I connect my login page to my user dashboard page?

I am using JAVA, Java swing, and MySQL database.

Comment: How do you know the user is male?

Comment: This is a question for stack overflow .

Comment: Hire a professional

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have mentioned, this is a question for Stack Overflow. That being said, here's an overview of the way login persistence works.

When a user successfully logs in, you'll want to create a "session" for that user. Sessions will need to be stored in a database table and have at least a "key", foreign key to the user table, and some way of indicating they have ended. You then set a cookie on the client that contains the session "key".

Whenever you need to retrieve user specific information or perform authorization, you know the user because it's associated with the current session.